# Network Problem While Reinstalling Grub

Tags: 11.10, networking, grub2, dns, chroot

I'm trying to reinstall grub on a second disk, following the instructions at [Purge & Reinstall Grub](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling_GRUB2).

After doing `sudo chroot /mnt`, when I attempt `apt-get update`, I get lot of `failed to fetch` messages. Apparently DNS is not working, since running the `host` command on any hostname times out: `no servers could be reached`.

If I exit the chroot, `host` and `apt-get update` work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description your chrooted environment has no information about valid nameservers (DNS). You can copy the file `/etc/resolv.conf` into the `etc` directory of your chroot environment. You could also edit the file `/mnt/etc/resolv.conf` (or if you are inside the chroot in `/etc/resolv.conf`) and add the line

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

This uses a nameserver from Google.

When your system has valid information about DNS servers it will work again as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the chroot, edit /etc/resolv.conf (`nano /etc/resolv.conf`) and insert the following line:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Name resolution should work now.

PS: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>,<kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file in `nano` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit.